# Credential in Django URL username:password@domain.com/?param=value

Tags: django, django-urls

My query is very simple, is it possible in Django to supply credentials in url scheme? I need it because I can easily curl it and at the same time I can keep get parameters free from weird values.

**For example** http://*username:password*@domain.com/?param=value

Comment: You know you can also do POST requests with cURL, see an example in C++ here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html.

Comment: Only GET requests are allowed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use this http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/ . Just  add decorator to your view  @logged_in_or_basicauth() from snippet.